# How to clear in memory array of char*?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have such array with size of `24 byte`:

```
char* arr[3] = {"CERN", "0", "ALK"};
printf("%ld\n", sizeof(arr));
```

Then I try to clear this array from memory by assigning `\0` to each element of array:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(char*); ++i) {
    arr[i] = '\0';
}
```

But when I want to check the size of array, it still gives me `24 byte`:

```
printf("%ld\n", sizeof(arr));
> 24
```

How to completely clear this array from memory that `sizeof(arr)` would give `0`?

Comment: Since this is a static array you cannot remove the variable from memory...

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(char*);` --> `sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);`

Comment: `arr[i] = '\0'` --> `arr[i] = NULL`

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(arr)` is the size of three `char*`. It doesn't change when you set each of the pointers to `0`.

> How to completely clear this array from memory that sizeof(arr) would
>   give 0?

There's no way to "clear" an array allocated on automatic storage. You really don't need to "clear" it at all.

Note that you should use `%zu` to print a `size_t` value, which is what `sizeof` operator yields. Using an incorrect format specifier is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: If I don't need to clear array ... what about memory leak?

Comment: Memory leak can happen only if you are using *dynamic memory allocation* such as using  `malloc()` or `calloc()` or `realloc()` or other functions that return pointer to dynamically allocated memory such as `strdup()`. There's no memory leak in your code. The array `arr` has three pointers allocated on automatic storage (aka, *stack*) and each of the pointers point to a *string literal* respectively. You haven't allocated memory for any of these yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned zeroes to the array, but that's all. You have not changed (and cannot, since you didn't `malloc()` it) the amount of memory allocated to the array, only cleared that data inside it.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no.  There are several different issues here:

1. If you want to clear a block of memory, use [memset()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)
2. If you want to zero out a string, all you need to do is set the FIRST character to null:  `arr[0] = 0;`
3. The [sizeof operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) tells you the size of your array.
4. The [strnlen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) tells you the length of your string.

Even if you've allocated 3 bytes for your array, the actual length of the string might be 0, 1 or 2.

It can never be "3" ... because you need at least one byte for your terminator.

Answer (score 1):

> How to completely clear this array from memory that `sizeof(arr)` would give `0`?

It is not possible given your declaration.

You'll have to come up with a different logic to come up with `0` -- the number of items in `arr` that are not NULL.

```
int my_own_array_size(char* arr[], int numElements)
{
   int count = 0;
   for ( int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i )
   {
      if ( arr[i] != NULL )
         ++count;
   }
   return count;
}
```

and then use it as:

```
int count = my_own_array_size(arr, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

> char* arr[3] = {"CERN", "0", "ALK"};

- Here **arr** is an array of 3 *char pointers*. Each element is of size 8 bytes (on 64 bit system).
- So size of **arr** will always be **24 (3* sizeof(void *))** irrespective of the memory referenced by pointers (viz. An address or NULL, which is further interpreted as char or string.This has nothing to do with **arr** size)
- Above **for loop** will only initialize the pointers to NULL.

> How to completely clear this array from memory that sizeof(arr) would give 0?

It is a static allocation (either an auto/global variable) . memory assigned for **arr** cannot be cleared.

note : In this case **"CERN", "0", "ALK"** are probably stored in **read only** segment.

Answer (score -1):

You may a look at this post since it explains the difference between statically and dynamically allocated memory:

[What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a comment.

Comment: it is the answer since it explains the concept. If the OP understands the concept he understands that the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: it is a link only answer and does not add any value as an answer.

Comment: we agree to disagree